# How to rewrite (P or Q) with AND

Tags: assembly, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-algebra, demorgans-law

I'm trying to write a XOR operation in assembly language, but the only operations we're allowed to use are AND and NOT, not OR and definitely not XOR. I have looked everywhere online and I can't seem to find the answer. I know:
XOR = **(P or Q)** and ~(P and Q)
But I need to rewrite **(P or Q)** with an AND operation instead. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7):

One of [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)<sup>(a)</sup> states that (using `~` for negation (not), `∧` for conjunction (and) and `∨` for disjunction (or)):

```
~A ∨ ~B = ~(A ∧ B)
```

In your case or `P ∨ Q`, `P` is `~A` and `Q` is `~B`. So:

```
P ∨ Q = ~(~P ∧ ~Q)
```

That right side is therefore the equivalent of `P ∨ Q`, using only `~` and `∧` operations.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> And a ***big*** thanks for letting me use this knowledge for about the third time since I left University in 1986 :-)

Comment: Ahh thank you! I had (~P and ~Q) but I did not get the same truth table as (P or Q). I was missing the extra 'not.'

Comment: Side note: in electronics you commonly use [nand logic to implement all kinds of functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_logic#OR) and you are allowed to use just that. Of course it's not the simplest solution.

Comment: @Jester, I remember doing that in the early days because the 74LS chips came in chunks (like several NAND gates to a chip). It was more efficient to use any spares to build an `OR` function than drop in *another* chip to do the work. Surely nowadays, you can get a million of each gate on a single chip though :-)

Comment: Yes, you could put a million gates on each chip, but you wouldn't have pins for each of them.  And the outside-facing ones need large enough transistors to drive TTL or CMOS levels over the capacitance of external wiring, and be at least somewhat resistant to ESD and short circuits...  There's a reason we have FPGAs and ASICs instead of 6-million-pin 74LS chips :)  But yeah good point.  A design might also want to use 2 of the same chip instead of 2 different chips to keep the bill-of-materials shorter.

Comment: Good point, @Peter, I totally forgot about the potentially large pin count :-)